# Electron change hostname

Tags: electron, capacitor

My Capacitor Electron app starts with hostname hyphen(-)

```
    capacitor-electron://-/
```

I want to change the hostname to some string, but can't find any option for this.

```
    capacitor-electron://abc/
```